# Reference a window variable with backbone view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm having quite a few issues with getting my backbone code to work now that I upgraded to backbone.js 0.9.2. One issue I'm having is referancing a variable in window. It worked fine like the below stripped down code in 0.5.3

Never mind the this.namespace.blaaaa bits basically I just have a namespace wrapper that takes care of putting the objects in a namespace. What I'm after here is why can't I access myApp from within side my PageDisplay view which is inside Page view. Seen as myApp is a window variable shouldn't I have access to this by calling it directly.

**myApp.js**

```
$(window).load(function() {
    myApp = new Page({ el: $("body"), scroll: $(window).scrollTop() });
})
```

**Page.js**

```
this.namespace.Page = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function( ) {
        this.pageDisplay = new PageDisplay({ 
            el: $("#showBrowser")
        });
    }
});
```

**PageDisplay.js**

```
this.namespace.PageDisplay = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function( ) {
        myApp.model.set("bla");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess that your `$(window).load()` handler:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    myApp = new Page({ el: $("body"), scroll: $(window).scrollTop() });
})
```

will fail because there is no `Page` in scope when it is called and, at best, `myApp` will be `undefined` when you try to `myApp.model.set()` later on. You define a `Page` inside your namespace:

```
this.namespace.Page = Backbone.View.extend({ /*...*/ });
```

and since `this` is presumably `window` in that context, you'd have `namespace.Page` but no `Page`. You'll have the same problem inside the `namespace.Page` initialization function:

```
this.pageDisplay = new PageDisplay({ 
    el: $("#showBrowser")
});
```

You'll have `namespace.PageDisplay` but no `PageDisplay`.

You should refer to `namespace.Page` and `namespace.PageDisplay` instead of just plain `Page` and `PageDisplay`. I'd also recommend that you drop the `this` when defining your views, that just causes confusion and opens up a window for bugs.

Answer (score 0):

I woul have the window as a view, as that is kind of what it is. You then have a the same behaviour you would with a window, but without the need for the render method (unless someone can think of one?). This way you can run those events for leaving a window and coming back, or resizing the whole window. Here's what I did:

```
var WindowView = Backbone.View.extend({
    "el": window,
    "events": {
        "resize": "onResize"
        "focus": "onFocus"
        "blur": "onBlur"
    },
    "onResize": function (ev) {

    },
    "onFocus": function (ev) {

    },
    "onBlur": function (ev) {

    }
});
```

Then you just create a new view like a standard view.